# Changing the devexpress layoutcontrolitem editor type?

Tags: c#, devexpress

How can I change the devexpress layoutcontrolitem editor type?

For example - change searchlookupedit to textedit then change it back.

I can change searchlookupedit to textedit but not vice versa.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void checkEdit1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkEdit1.Checked)
        {
            ConvertEditorType("TextEdit", searchLookUpEdit1, layoutControlItem1);
            //this.Text = searchLookUpEdit1.GetType().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ConvertEditorType("SearchLookUpEdit", searchLookUpEdit1, layoutControlItem1);
            //this.Text = searchLookUpEdit1.GetType().ToString();
        }
    }
    private void ConvertEditorType(string editorTypeName, BaseEdit sourceEditor, LayoutControlItem layout)
    {
        layout.Owner.BeginUpdate();
        EditorClassInfo info = EditorRegistrationInfo.Default.Editors[editorTypeName];
        if (info == null) return;
        BaseEdit edit = info.CreateEditor();
        //this.Text = edit.GetType().ToString();
        edit.Location = sourceEditor.Location;
        edit.Size = sourceEditor.Size;
        edit.Parent = sourceEditor.Parent;
        edit.Properties.Assign(sourceEditor.Properties);
        layout.Control = edit;
        layout.Owner.EndUpdate();
        sourceEditor.Dispose();
        sourceEditor = null;
    }
```

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution from DevExpress I used few years ago. I think it worth taking a look.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q353927/converting-one-control-to-another-at-run-time

Basically they have a custom EditorConverter class which does what you need. It reassigns a lot of properties and data bindings. Maybe you don't need everyting in the class but when I use it with your code example it seems to work as expected.